# Converting a series of DateTime values to the proper format

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, matplotlib

Currently, I have a series of Datetime Values that display as so

```
0  Datetime
1  20041001
2  20041002
3  20041003
4  20041004
```

they are within a series named

```
d['Datetime']
```

They were originally something like
    20041001ABCDEF
But I split the end off just to leave them with the remaining numbers. How do I go about putting them into the following format?

```
2004-10-01
```

Comment: Presumably you tried `to_datetime`. What were the errors you faced?

Comment: @roganjosh I got an error saying "time data 'Datetime' does not match format '%y%m%d' (match). Although seeing as my datetime value line up with that I'm not sure how that's the case.

Comment: You need to be a bit careful with the `formats`. For a lot of functions, pandas is fairly sloppy and allows `Year` to be parsed as `'y'` or `'Y'`. But for `%y` in the format argument means it's the `year without century as a zero-padded decimal number` See http://strftime.org/ for a list of all formatting variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following,

```
df['Datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Datetime'], format='%Y%m%d'))
```